# Sql Loader error "Token longer than max allowable length of 258 chars"

Tags: sql-loader

I am getting the below error on loading the data to a table using SQL Loader.

```
SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 21.
Token longer than max allowable length of 258 chars
                                                                    ')
                                                  ^
```

The control file is as below:

```
OPTIONS (SKIP = 1)
LOAD DATA 

APPEND
PRESERVE BLANKS
INTO TABLE "INTL"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
TRAILING NULLCOLS

(
CO_BDI_INTERLOCUTOR CHAR(15),
NU_DOCUMENTO    CHAR(17),
CO_TRATAMIENTO  CHAR(1) "NVL(:CO_TRATAMIENTO,' ')",
DS_NOMBRE   CHAR(50),
DS_APELLIDO_1   CHAR(50),
DS_APELLIDO_2   CHAR(50),
CO_CARGO    CHAR(2) "NVL(:CO_CARGO,'  ')",
DS_COMENTARIO   CHAR(255) "NVL(:DS_COMENTARIO,'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ')",
DS_ARE_FUN_ITL_GRC  CHAR(100),
FX_INI_VIGENCIA CHAR(10),
FX_FIN_VIGENCIA CHAR(10) "NVL(:FX_FIN_VIGENCIA,'          ')",
CO_CUC_CLIENTE  CHAR(8),
CO_CUC_CABECERA CHAR(8),
CO_HITO CHAR(8),
DS_SIS_ORIGEN   CHAR(4),
CO_INTERLOCUTOR CHAR(15),
CO_TIPO_DOC CHAR(1),
CO_IDIOMA   CHAR(3)
)
```

The problem seems to be with the field "DS_COMENTARIO" since I am replacing the data with spaces of length 255 if the field is NULL.

I have a similar problem with other table and Control file also.

Could you please help me with this?

Thanks,
Savitha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

DS_COMENTARIO   CHAR(255) "NVL(:DS_COMENTARIO,LPAD(' ', 255, ' ')",

It basically pads a 1 Character string out to 255 characters.